# SPARQL Filter not working

Tags: sparql

I'm running the following SPARQL query on [de.dbpedia](http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql)

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
{
    ?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein.
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
Optional {?name <http://de.dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?deathDate}
MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
}
union{
    SERVICE silent <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
    ?name dcterms:subject category-en:Princely_Family_of_Liechtenstein.
    ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
Optional {?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?deathDate}
}
MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
}
}
```

For the "DE-Results", the MINUS-filter works fine, but for the "EN-Results" I'm also getting persons with a deathDate. Can anyone explain me why this filter doesn't apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bracketting in your query:  the **minus** in the "right hand side" of the **union** has a **service** form, and a **minus**, but the **minus** is *outside* of the **service** form:

```
union{
    SERVICE silent <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
      ?name dcterms:subject category-en:Princely_Family_of_Liechtenstein.
      ?name rdf:type foaf:Person.
      Optional {?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?deathDate}
    }
    MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
}
```

That said, I'm not sure what the point of optionally binding a death date with:

```
Optional {?name <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?deathDate}
```

is if you're just going to remove anyone with a death date with:

```
MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
```

After all, **dbpedia-owl:** is usually a prefix defined as **http://dbpedia.org/ontology/**.